# Configure subdomain at rails - apache - passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, subdomain

I have an application, working at domain **example.com**, I want configure subdomains **ru.example.com**. 
Rails + Passenger + Apache

/etc/apache2/sites-available/example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/public  
  <Directory /var/www/myapp/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried copy VirtualHost section and change ServerName to ru.example.com and restart apache by command "apachectl restart", but address "ru.example.com" don't work

What i need to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I need to contact DNS provider and open subdomains, in conf - only copy VH section with different ServerName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an entry in your hosts file for `ru.example.com` to point to `127.0.0.1`. Not sure your OS, but you should be able to find the steps on Google, it's pretty easy.

Edit:

Try adding this line to your config:

```
ServerAlias example.com ru.example.com
```

Comment: This application works in production now, I don't need work throw localhost - this has real IP address, i want connect from any device.

Comment: After edit:
I add line
"ServerAlias example.com ru.example.com"
but no result. Maybe i need contact with domain seller about it?